# SessionsHelper in railstutorial.org: Should helpers be general-purpose modules for code not needed in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encapsulation, helper, railstutorial.org

railstutorial.org has a suggestion which strikes me as a little odd.

[It suggests this code](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code%3asessions_helper_include):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  protect_from_forgery 
  include SessionsHelper 
end
```

The `include SessionsHelper` makes the methods available from `ApplicationController`, yes, but it makes them available in any view, as well. I understand that authentication/authorization is cross-cutting, but is this really the best place?

That seems to me to be potentially too broad of a scope. Putting code which implements, say, a `before_filter` which conditionally redirects (as the railstutorial.org example does) in a module which more commonly contains view helpers seems surprising.

Would functionality not strictly needed in views be better placed in ApplicationController or elsewhere?

Or am I just thinking too much about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed, your feeling is correct.

I would implement this the other way around: add the functions `sign_in` and `current_user` to `ApplicationController` (or if you really want to: in a separate module defined in `lib` and include it), and then make sure that the `current_user` method is available in the view.

In short:

```
class ApplicationController

  helper_method :current_user

  def sign_in

  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end
end
```

Of course, if you have a lot of code to place into your `ApplicationController` it can get messy. In that case I would create a file `lib\session_management.rb`:

```
module SessionManagement
  def self.included(base)
    base.helper_method :current_user
  end

  def sign_in
    ..
  end

  def current_user
    ..
  end
end
```

and inside your controller you can then just write:

```
class ApplicationController
  include SessionManagement
end
```

Comment: The `base.helper :current_user code` is incorrect, it should be `base.send :helper_method, : current_user`

Comment: Thank you @kain, small typo. It should be `helper_method`. But you can just write `base.helper_method, :current_user`.

Comment: nub question: in this case, what's the difference between using a SessionHelper and using a SessionManagment module? isn't a helper just another module?

Comment: Helper files, located under `app/helpers` are included in the views automatically. As such it is expected to contain simple view functionality. That is why I would recommend placing it in a separate module: it contains more than just view functionality. In rails 4 terminology this appraoch has been formalised: they are now called `concerns`.

Answer (score 6):

They *seem* to be taking (sneaky) advantage of the fact that, in Rails, Helpers are just ruby Modules.

Placing behavior that is shared across Controllers in a Module is, in my opinion, good practice.  Putting it in a Helper, on the other hand, is potentially misleading and I would avoid it.  Place it in a “standard” Module.

Answer (score 4):

This is a *philosophical* question on the same level as the argument that questions the REST method provided in scaffolding and if A scaffold is worth having at all. You have to consider the fact that the tutorial book in RailsTutorial.org is a get-up-and-go Rails instructive guide. So for the purpose which it serves, I think it does the job.

However, is there a better place to put code needed across controllers and views? Yes, there is.

- Some may follow Michael Hartl form Railstutorial and include the entire `SessionHelper` into the `ApplicationController`
- Others may decide to expose only the essential helpers needed for the view i.e. `sign_in`, `sign_out`, `current_user` and the like.
- I see a suggestion to put such code in the `/lib` directory and include it where needed.

All are viable options. Whichever you take may not matter that much in performance because Ruby would have to parse the file which you want to call (or include) a class, module or method from. What happens is, before any code is executed in a class, Ruby goes through the whole class once to know what's in it. It all depends on what one needs and the design of their app

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I store the current user in the User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current
  ...
end
```

This can be referenced in all 3 MVC tiers; it is set in the controller like so (and likewise on login, of course):

```
def set_current_user
  User.current = (session[:user_id]) ? User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) : nil
end
```

Among other things, this allows me to have audit logs at the ActiveRecord level that capture the current user (when applicable).

Comment: Would this create a concurrency problem?

Comment: I do not have any concurrency problems as long as User.current is set within the ApplicationController. There was the time I moved setting User.current in AuthenticatedSystem's module file in lib - and did have concurrency problems (possibly related to a bug in that changed code - I reverted without bothering to investigate too much). Now I have an integration test that checks for concurrency problems :).