# Ruby on Rails Chapter 9 Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I'm most of the way through chapter 9. For some reason I keep getting these three errors, I checked with the github to see what if I was missing anything, but I have exactly what I should have. Here are my errors:

```
    1) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign out" }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `sign_out' for #<SessionsController:0x104c0b9d0>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `destroy'
     # (eval):2:in `send'
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:44

  2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users when attempting to visit a protected page after signing in should render the desired protected page
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Edit user')
       expected css "title" with text "Edit user" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:65

  3) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users when attempting to visit a protected page after signing in when signing in again should render the default (profile) page
     Failure/Error: click_link "Sign out"
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `sign_out' for #<SessionsController:0x104c358c0>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `destroy'
     # (eval):2:in `send'
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:70
```

My authentication_pages_spec.rb file:

```
 require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do

    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    :text => 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('h1','title', :text => 'Sign in') }
end


    describe "signin" do

    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('h1', 'title', :text => 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', :text => user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',  :href => user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', :href => signout_path) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', :href => edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Users',    :href => users_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', :href => signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    :with => user.email
          fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do
          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Edit user')
          end

          describe "when signing in again" do
            before do
              click_link "Sign out"
              click_link "Sign in"
              fill_in "Email",    :with => user.email
              fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
              click_button "Sign in"              
            end

            it "should render the default (profile) page" do
              page.should have_selector('title', :text => user.name)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', :text => 'Sign in') }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-notice') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_selector('title', :text => 'Sign in') }
        end
      end

     describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('h1', 'title', :text => full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

My sessions_controller.rb file:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because there is no `sign_out` method defined in your `SessionsController` or in the parent `ApplicationController` it inherits from.

According to the Rails tutorial in chapter 8 he has you [define this method in](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-sign_out_method) the `SessionsHelper`, which is then [mixed in](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-sessions_helper_include) to the `ApplicationController`.  I think mixing helpers into controllers is not good (helpers should be restricted to views; [others agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500322/sessionshelper-in-railstutorial-org-should-helpers-be-general-purpose-modules-f)), but that's the way the tutorial is laid out for you.

Comment: ohhhh! I think I must have quit without saving and my sessionsHelper didn't get saved. Thank you for finding that mistake! I appreciate the hyperlink too

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking `sign_out` in a `SessionsController` instance, but there is no such method defined.  Check the code in your "Sign out" view and check your `routes.rb` file to make sure that whatever link you're choosing is mapped properly.  Usually, "sign out" is mapped to the `destroy` method.

Comment: In my routes.rb file I have match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :via => :delete

I've been following the tutorial and I think these are the only 3 times that "sign out" is defined

Comment: What about your view code - whatever is invoked by the `click_link "Sign out"`?

Comment: Would you share the output of `rake routes` also?

Comment: Yeah, never mind.  `sign_out` is invoked by the `Sessions#destroy` defined in Figure 8.29 and as the other answer indicated, is proposed to be defined in a helper file as shown in Figure 8.30