# Ruby on Rails: ApplicationController methods undefined? (beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

The logged_in? method shows up as undefined in PrescriptionsController, but not in UsersController. This is really weird because they both extend ApplicationController, where the logged_in_user method exists. The logged_in? method is in the SessionsHelper module.

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index] //this shows up as undefined

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index]  //but this is ok

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   # Confirms a logged-in user.
   def logged_in_user
       unless logged_in?
           flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
           redirect_to login_url
       end
   end

module SessionsHelper
   # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
 def logged_in?
   !current_user.nil?
 end
```

The Error:

```
    undefined method `logged_in?' for #<PrescriptionsController:0x007f441ce66cb8>
```

Comment: can u put error here ?

Comment: Where does `logged_in?` come from or is it defined by some gem you have installed? This isn't a problem with the method you've defined, but with the call you've made within that method.

Comment: sorry about that; I clarified it. The logged_in? method is in SessionsHelper.

Comment: And how/where is the session helper loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your `application.rb` put this

```
class ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Also refer this [SessionsHelper in railstutorial.org: Should helpers be general-purpose modules for code not needed in views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500322/sessionshelper-in-railstutorial-org-should-helpers-be-general-purpose-modules-f)